# Why is water standing on packaged HVAC unit trunk that is under the floor

Tags: hvac

I bought a house with a packaged HVAC Unit that has a trunk that runs directly under the sub floor. When pulling up the old vinyl flooring the contractor noticed that a section of plywood below was discolored and upon pulling up the plywood found that there was water standing on top of the metal trunk. Because the rest of the subfloor appears dry and because after pulling the baseboard the wall adjacent to the affected area was dry, the contractor feels that the standing water is the result of condensation and that there needs to be some way to allow air to pass across the top of the trunk to allow for evaporation. An electrician who also does installation of HVAC units and is working at the house said that the standing water must be the result of rainwater seeping down the wall, because since restarting the unit a couple of weeks ago (was not used for at least 4 months and probably longer) it has only been run for heat and that would not cause condensation.

1. From the information above which explanation sounds more likely?
2. Is there a remedy if the contractor is correct?

Comment: A couple thoughts made as a comment, since they're not really answers.  1. What type of furnace is it?  If it's a high-efficiency, where does the condensation line run, and could that be leaking onto your duct work?  What was previously above this area, and could something have leaked down through vinyl floor cracks onto the ducts?  And to confirm your electrician's thoughts, has it been rainy there recently?  If not, that seems like a bad guess.

Comment: 4 months should be enough time for water to evaporate, assuming the 4 months the HVAC unit was not on/doing anything.  Condensation should only occur if cool/cold air was blowing though the trunk(AC on).   Of the two reasons, a leak(rain or pipe) is probably more than 50% possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure of the details of your installation, but AC units are expected to generate water from the air via condensation, it is the rate of water generation that is the issue.  Condensation only happens when something cold pulls humidity out of the air, turning it into water.

So, if you have a high amount of confidence that the AC hasn't run in months, the water didn't come from the AC, unless that water sees so little air movement that it is multi-month old water.

Odds are it is the rainwater seepage, but one should also look for any other reasons.

To see this in action, take a glass and put it on the countertop.  Notice how water doesn't form on its sides.  Now fill the glass up with ice water.  Notice how condensation eventually forms on the outside of the glass.  If the AC isn't generating cold air in the compressor, it doesn't have a source of "cold stuff" to pull the humidity out of the air.

That said, after you fix the water issue, I would run the AC for a few hours and check to see if there is water in the pan under the AC, and if there is no pan under the AC, consider having one put in place, even if the unit contains an internal pan.  Water condensation from an AC can do a lot of damage before it gets noticed, and a pan ideally has a drain, but even if it doesn't it will provide an easy visual check.  Finally, there are float cut-off switches that can be attached to the external pan, which if installed/operating properly, will cut the power to the unit should water accumulate in the pan.  It's a lot easier on a pocketbook to suffer having no ac for a bit of time as you get the issues fixed than to discover water in the building and remediate it.